# Using Executor framework of multi threading to process data

Tags: java

I am working on an application where I have to retrieve large amount of data from database and write it to the file. For doing this I am planning to use Executor framework to improve performance of my application. I have two list and my code is as follows.

```
for(String n:studentNameList){
    for(String s:studentClassList){
        // here I will call a method which will take result set object and will write data to the file
    }
}
```

Both these list contains large amount of data. For every combination of name
and class it will make a file in output directory. Without multithreading code is working fine but to improve performance I read some articles and got to know that I can use executor framework to improve performance. I haven't used it earlier and I don't have good command over multithreading. I am doing it using executor framework as follows:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for(String n:studentNameList){
    service.submit(n);
    for(String s:studentClassList){
        service.submit(s);
        // here I will call a method which will take result set object and will write data to the file
    }
}
service.shutdown();
```

Am I doing it right. Is it the correct way by which I can process more records.Please suggest. Please tell me where I am wrong and how I can correct it if needed.

Comment: The ```ExecutorService.submit``` method takes a Callable<T> or a Runnable as parameter

Comment: i think runnable

Comment: You also have an overload that takes a ```Callable<T>```: [doc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). You are using a String instead

Answer (score 1):

Your core logic is
`void getAndSaveData(String name, String class) { ... }`

Single threaded execution code is:

```
for ( String name : students ) {
    for ( String clazz : classes ) {
       getAndSaveData(name, clazz);
    }
}
```

To convert it to multithreaded mode wrap call to the method into:

```
ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for ( String name : students ) {
    for ( String clazz : classes ) {
       Runnable r = () -> getAndSaveData(name, clazz);
       executors.submit(r);
    }
}

executors.shutdown(); // marks that no new tasks will come
// wait for 5 minutes before proceeding
boolean allDone = executors.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
// allDone will have status have everything completed in 5 minutes or not
```

More details can be found in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: thanks buddy I will try this, One more simple question can I call my method to fetch data and file writing just after executors.submit(r). Will I get multiple files at same time?

Comment: Hey this code is giving error in bracket near lambda expression.. Can you please tell how to resolve it?

Comment: In eclipse it is showing syntax error near tokens () - >, expression needed instead